# Проблемы с регулярным выражением php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

здравствуйте, есть регулярка для проверки ника при регистрации `~^[^-_][a-zA-Z_\-0-9]*$~u` но почему-то пользователь может ввести такой #ник , хэштег одобряется только если он стоит как первый символ, не подскажите как это исправить?

Comment: Наверное, вы хотите сделать так, чтобы первый символ был отличен от `-` и `_`? Используйте `~^(?![-_])[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$~u`, или даже `~^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][\w-]*)?$~`.

Comment: У вас ник может начинать со всего что угодно, кроме "-" и "_", судя по `[^-_]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон `[^-_]` является *исключающим* символьным классом, он находит любой символ, олтличный от знака `-` и `_` (т.е. очень много символов).

Удалите его:

```
~^[a-zA-Z_0-9-]*$~
```

Это выражение легко сокращается до

```
~^[\w-]*$~
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/QqoXXW/2)

Если пустые строки не разрешены, замените квантификатор `*` на `+`:

```
~^[\w-]+$~
```

**Подробности**

- `^` -начало строки
- `[\w-]*` - 0 и более букв/цифр/`_` (`\w`) и/или `-`
- `$` - конец строки.

Кстати, если нужно сделать так, чтобы `$` найти позицию непосредственно в конце строки, используйте модификатор `D`: `~^[\w-]*$~D`.

Comment: Модификатор `u` потеряли во втором варианте.

Comment: @sanmai В оригинальной версии выражения - `~^[^-_][a-zA-Z_\-0-9]*$~u` - нет ни одного символа Юникода. Я полагаю, разрешается только набор ASCII. Модификатор `u` позволит `\w` находить любые буквы и цифры Юникода. Подождём ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите как сделать чтобы можно было добавить "-" и "_" в начало ника? Просто в принципе, меня устраивало мое выражение, просто в начало нико можно было вводить "#"

Comment: @Владимир Кажется, надо просто удалить `(?![-_])`: `~^[a-zA-Z_0-9-]*$~` / `~^[\w-]*$~D`

Answer (score -1):

Пусть ник начинается только на букву, а содержит буквы, цифры и знаки "_" и "-"

```
~^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_\-0-9]*$~u
```